# MySQL: Select row by id, CHANGE id, and insert it into another table

Tags: mysql, select, insert, pdo

I have two tables, A and B.

I'd like to select a row from B based on it's Primary Key, alter the primary key to a different value, and then insert this row into A.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO A SELECT id, title, date FROM B WHERE B.id="4" UPDATE B SET id="5";
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Original poster here: Just a note, A and B have identical columns.

Comment: where do you want this changed id, in original row (table B) or in newly inserted (table A) ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  You want to do it in a single query?

Comment: It should have the new value inserted into A.

Comment: are you just incrementing id by 1 or is there some other formula whats the data type

Comment: The increment by one is just an example. I'll actually be drastically changing the values. The data type is int.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO A(id, title, date)
SELECT 5 AS id, title, date FROM B WHERE B.id="4";
#      ^--- here is the trick
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
insert into a (select id as "new_id", title, date from b where b.id="4")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would select id as "new_id" let me change the id value to whatever is in the quotes?